# finding repeated combinations in a list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

User enters Username, password and system generates unique field. *Each* username password combination along with an auto generated unique field is stored in a List as an object.
I want to find out if the username-password combination is repeated or not in the list (without considering the unique key).

I wanted to avoid using for loops to figure this out. Using hashmap to find out if there are repeated combinations-

```
//hm is the hashmap...
//up is the list....
for(int i=0; i<up.length(); i++){
  if(hm.contains(up[i])){
    System.out.println("Repeated combination");
    break;
    }
   else{
       hm.put(up[i],i);
    }
 }
```

However the object has a unique auto generated field and the above logic wouldn't work. Any suggestions to achieve this in the fastest possible way.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that up[i] is some class(User) which has username, password and unique_id as three fields.

If that's true you can create wrapper around this class(UserWrapper) and override equals/hashCode methods to rely only on username/password attributes of User class.

That should be really quick to code/test

EDIT: Sample classes are below. You could you LinkedHashMap (so you'll have map functionality and still have users ordered in the same way as you put them in)

```
class User {
    private final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof User) {
            User user = (User) obj;
            return id.equals(user.getId()) &&
                    username.equals(user.getUsername()) &&
                    password.equals(user.getPassword());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode() + username.hashCode() * 31 + password.hashCode() * 31 * 31;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

Wrapper:

```
class UserWrapper {
    private final User user;

    public UserWrapper(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof UserWrapper) {
            UserWrapper userWrapper = (UserWrapper) obj;
            return user.getUsername().equals(userWrapper.getUser().getUsername()) &&
                    user.getPassword().equals(userWrapper.getUser().getPassword());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return user.getUsername().hashCode() + user.getPassword().hashCode() * 31;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Finder:

```
class DuplicateUserFinder {

    public List<UserWrapper> findDuplicates(List<UserWrapper> allUsers) {
        final List<UserWrapper> duplicateList = new ArrayList<UserWrapper>();
        final Set<UserWrapper> duplicateSet = new HashSet<UserWrapper>();

        for (UserWrapper wrapper : allUsers) {
            if (duplicateSet.contains(wrapper)) {
                duplicateList.add(wrapper);
            } else {
                duplicateSet.add(wrapper);
            }
        }

        return duplicateList;
    }

}
```

Unit Test:

```
public class DuplicateUserFinderTest {

    private final DuplicateUserFinder finder = new DuplicateUserFinder();

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnEmptyIfNoDuplicates() {
        User user1 = new User("user1", "pass1");
        User user2 = new User("user2", "pass2");
        UserWrapper userWrapper1 = new UserWrapper(user1);
        UserWrapper userWrapper2 = new UserWrapper(user2);

        Assert.assertTrue(finder.findDuplicates(Arrays.asList(userWrapper1, userWrapper2)).isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDuplicates() {
        User user1 = new User("user", "pass");
        User user2 = new User("user", "pass");
        UserWrapper userWrapper1 = new UserWrapper(user1);
        UserWrapper userWrapper2 = new UserWrapper(user2);

        Assert.assertTrue(finder.findDuplicates(Arrays.asList(userWrapper1, userWrapper2)).contains(userWrapper2));
        Assert.assertThat(finder.findDuplicates(Arrays.asList(userWrapper1, userWrapper2)).size(), CoreMatchers.equalTo(1));
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes as you said it has 3 fields. Can you please explain how exactly can I achieve that. So you want to say I would still use hashmap or directly use the List?

Comment: do you mean something like public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this.username == obj.username && this.pwd==obj.pwd)
        return true;
    else
    return false;
}

Comment: I've provided examples for classes (ignoring possible null values).

Comment: this.username == obj.username - don't use it since it's test for object equality, use equals method instead.

Comment: my bad i wanted to key .equals() Thanks!

Comment: the initial code in the question I had provided I wanted to avoid using loops to iterate over the list of objects more than once. So i was using the .containsKey() method of hashmap. How can I still use the containsKey() ? I just want to loop over the list of objects only once and within that 1 complete loop over the list I want to figure out if there is a username- password combination repeating (assuming all are stored in plain text not encrypted).

Comment: I think I know what you are after. I've updated answer with sample code for search - uses loop only once and uses Set (you don't really need hashmap). Unit test is for documenting expectations. You still need to have code somewhere for User>UserWrapper and UserWrapper->User transformations. I'd use Lamdaj for that.